# Translate the linear address to the corresponding logical address in Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In the function `struct page *rmqueue(..)` I am extracting the physical address using `page_to_phys(page)` and the linear address (also called as [virtual address](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html)) using `page_address(page)`. My question is how do I extract the logical address generated by the OS so that I can complete my mapping overview from Logical ---> linear ---> Physical address space.

Is it just an offset for the x86 that I need to subtract from the segmantation unit or is it something else?

Comment: So virtual and physical addresses are both linear, though the physical address space may have some gaps in it (unlikely on most systems). What do you mean by "logical address"?

Comment: Logical address that the CPU generates which this then passed on the segmentation unit to generate the linear address and which passes on the paging unit to generate the physical address. 
Now I understand I can always extract the logical address using a `&var` but I need to see a mapping from which pages are the ones used by my allocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on surfing through the code, I found a function called `struct page *
alloc_pages_vma(gfp_t gfp, int order, struct vm_area_struct *vma,
                unsigned long addr, int node, bool hugepage)` in `mm/mempolicy.c` on my linux kernel 4.14.4+ 
The parameter unsigned long addr is the logical address. The page can be accessed from the function from which the physical address and the linear address(virtual) can be extracted too with the functions already mentioned in the question.